# npm install loads modules not in package.js

Tags: npm

I have a package.json file that looks like this.

```
    {
      "name": "package",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "wordpress",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "^0.4.5",
        "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.9.0",
        "load-grunt-tasks": "^0.4.0",
        "grunt-bower-install": "~0.7.0",
        "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.7.3",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
        "grunt-concat-css": "^0.3.1",
        "matchdep": "^0.3.0",
        "grunt-bower-install": "^1.6.0",
        "grunt-modernizr": "^0.5.2",
        "grunt-notify": "~0.2.3"
      }
    }
```

When I run

```
npm install
```

It creates a node_modules folder, adds the modules in the package.json file but also adds lots of other modules that I haven't referenced.

Comment: If you recently upgraded your node version, or upgraded npm from 2.x to 3.x, know that the latest version "flattens" out the directory structure under `node_modules`.  Instead of having modules nested in modules, as with 2.x, all modules are installed at the root of `node_modules`.  This helps with a few things, like path length, that can be an issue on Windows systems.  My guess is this is what you're seeing, but you didn't know the change was introduced with v3.x.

Answer (score 0):

The extra modules you're seeing are the dependencies of the modules you've explicitly installed - in other words, it's the things *they* have listed in their `package.json`. For example, if you install the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module, [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) will get installed as well, as `async` depends on it to be able to work.

Comment: Im positive this never used to happen. The modules that are dependencies are normally in the node_module folder inside the module I have explicitly installed.

Comment: @ttmt: You're right, it didn't always work this way! NPM 3 (which is included by default in new versions of Node) uses a flat directory strucure instead of nesting the modules, as it makes deduping easier and fixes filename length issues on Windows. See https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3.